# symfony2 twig html tags

Tags: html, templates, symfony, twig

I'm fairly new with twig, so I'm having a little trouble.
I pass a variable to my twig template in Symfony2

```
  <p>{{ var.description|length > 100 ? var.description|slice(0, 100) ~ '...' : var.description }}</p>
```

this variable contains html tags that were showing up so I stripped them

```
  <p>{{ var.description|striptags|length > 100 ? var.description|striptags|slice(0, 100) ~ '...' : var.description|striptags }}</p>
```

But then the links and features don't work.  Is there a way to just output the html from the variable in a functional way?

Comment: [`|raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the first 100 characters of the description as html use this:

```
<p>{{ var.description|length > 100 ? var.description|raw|slice(0, 100) ~ '...' : var.description }}</p>
```

using the raw filter will allow html tags to be rendered.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: Note: if there's less than 100 char, they are not rendered as HTML (last part of the expression). Furthermore, the 100 chars counted here includes the html code.